# Wrappers and Access Violation

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, operator-overloading, wrapper

Here is my problem :
I created a generic wrapper class to handle memory management for some other classes I have where i have implemented a clone method which is supposed to clone the object by providing a new object (and new pointer to it) :

```
template <class T>
class Wrapper
{
public :
    Wrapper() { DataPtr = 0; }

    Wrapper(const T& inner) 
    { 
        if (DataPtr != 0)
            DataPtr = inner.clone();
        else
            DataPtr = 0;
    }

    ~Wrapper()
    {
        if (DataPtr != 0)
            delete DataPtr;
    }

    Wrapper& operator=(Wrapper& original)
    { 
        if (this != &original) 
        {
            delete DataPtr;
            DataPtr = DataPtr = 0 ? 0 : original.DataPtr->clone();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return *DataPtr;
    }

    T* operator->() 
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }

    const T& operator*() const
    {
        return *DataPtr;
    }

    const T* operator->() const
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }

private :
    T* DataPtr;
};
```

Say I have a Class that uses in it's private attributes Wrapper < Class2 > Obj; which has a clone method :

my issue is that trying to call any member using the overloaded access operator -> gives me :
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF6122D4102 in Training.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

And I don't understand why I don't have access since DataPtr is a member of the Wrapper Class

Both dereferencing the wrapper by doing (*Obj).SomeMethod() and using the -> operator by doing
Obj->SomeMethod() give the same results.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to include one. Since this is a debugging question, your code snippet should contain the `Class2` class mentioned in the description, and a minimal `main` function that demonstrates the memory access problem.

Comment: sorry this is my first time using StackOverFlow, I actually found my problem, in the wrapper class, my operator= overloading is complete rubish 
which should be : 
```
Wrapper& operator=(Wrapper& original)
    { 
        if (this != &original) 
        {
            delete DataPtr;
            DataPtr = original.DataPtr == 0 ? 0 : original.DataPtr->clone();
        }
        return *this;
    }
```
Somehow the compiler didn't complain

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Glad that you found the answer yourself. Note that [answering your own question **is encouraged** on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so you may also consider posting a proper answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue after all was that my `operator=` overload had a problem: After deleting `DataPtr`, I tried checking if `DataPtr` was null while it didn't exist. What I should do, instead, is check if the `DataPtr` of the object I want to assign (i.e. original) was null.

Below is the corrected code :

```
template <class T>

class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper() { DataPtr = 0; } // the default constructor which point to nothing
    Wrapper(const T& inner) // constructor
    {
        DataPtr = inner.Clone();
    }
    ~Wrapper()
    {
        delete DataPtr;
    }

    Wrapper(const Wrapper<T>& original) // copy constructor when pass in a Wrapper class
    {
        if (original.DataPtr != 0)
            DataPtr = original.DataPtr->Clone();
        else
            DataPtr = 0;
    }

    // return by reference to avoid unnecessary copy
    Wrapper& operator= (const Wrapper<T>& oringinal)// overloading "=" assignement operator
    {
        if (this != &oringinal)
        {
            if (DataPtr != 0)
            {
                delete DataPtr;
                DataPtr = (oringinal.DataPtr != 0) ? oringinal.DataPtr.Clone() : 0;
            }

        }
        return  *this; // return what this point to
    }

    // two version of dereferencing operator *
    // dereference both const and non-const objects
    T& operator*() // overloading "*" to get object from pointer
    {
        return *DataPtr;
    }

    const T& operator*() const // return a const object
    {
        return *DataPtr;
    }

    // overloading "->" to access method within pointed object
    const T* operator ->() const
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }

    T* operator ->()
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }


private:
    T* DataPtr;
};
```

Comment: There are more problems with this code: 1. Checking `if (DataPtr != 0)` in a constructor is useless, since it's unintialized. 2. You forgot the copy constructor. 3. Copy assignment should accept the parameter by a const reference. 4. `if (DataPtr != 0)` in destructor is useless, `delete` checks this automatically. 5. Adding a move constructor and assignment would be good too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, absolutely right!